# How to implement URL rewriting with Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, azure, query-string

I have an ASP.NET / C# website that's hosted on Windows Azure.  The site is a predictions-based social site with a feed of prediction summaries on the main page. If you click on a summary, you're redirected to the details page for that prediction using a simple QueryString.

For example:

http://www.ipredikt.com/details.aspx?id=14

This particular prediction is entitled *"Paris Hilton will win the Nobel Peace Prize"* so what I'd like to do is **implement URL rewriting** for my site on **Azure** as follows:

http://www.ipredikt.com/predictions/14/paris-hilton-will-win-the-nobel-peace-prize

What are some strategies and best practices for doing this? And can someone point me to a good Azure-specific article or two.

The hyphenated title ("paris-hilton-bla-bla") is really just to make the URL more human readable; I don't envision relying on it at all in terms of loading pages. In fact, I'd probably allow duplicate titles since I'll be relying on the prediction ID in the URL.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that we are **NOT** based on MVC. We came up w/ our own architecture that uses PageMethods and WebMethods to return JSON to the client. We rely on ASP.NET AJAX to do all of the JSON serialization, and almost all of our UI is built dynamically on the client using jQuery.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thought I'd share my solution now that I have things up and running.

I made a new class as follows (copied verbatim from somewhere):

```
public class WebFormRouteHandler<T> : IRouteHandler where T : IHttpHandler, new()
{
   public string VirtualPath { get; set; }

   public WebFormRouteHandler(string virtualPath)
   {
      this.VirtualPath = virtualPath;
   }

   public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
   {
      return (VirtualPath != null)
          ? (IHttpHandler)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, typeof(T))
          : new T();
   }
}
```

I added the following method to Global.asax.  The actual method is MUCH, much longer (it covers every page in the site). You'll see that I support calling the predictions page in lots of different ways: with an id, with an id + title, etc. (The "...fb" versions of pages are for the Facebook app version of my site which use a different MasterPage.)

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
     // Details : 'predictions' Page
     var routeHandlerDetails = new WebFormRouteHandler<Page>("~/details.aspx");
     var routeHandlerDetailsFb = new WebFormRouteHandler<Page>("~/detailsfb.aspx");

     routes.Add(new Route("predictions/{id}", routeHandlerDetails));
     routes.Add(new Route("predictions/{id}/{title}", routeHandlerDetails));

     routes.Add(new Route("fb/predictions/{id}", routeHandlerDetailsFb));
     routes.Add(new Route("fb/predictions/{id}/{title}", routeHandlerDetailsFb));
   }
```

...and this method is called from Application_Start()

```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  }
```

Then I added the following to web.config in the system.webServer block:

```
   <!-- Added for URL Routing -->
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   </modules>

    <!-- Added for URL Routing -->
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
           preCondition="integratedMode"
           verb="*"
           path="UrlRouting.axd"
           type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
   </handlers>
```

I also had to exclude the virtual "predictions" directory from authentication (because almost all parts of our site are accessible my non-auth users):

```
<!-- Url routing -->
<location path="predictions">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Finally, I no longer rely on QueryString string parameters when loading pages, so I had to write some new helper methods.  Here's one that extracts a numerical value from the new routing URL (I'll be cleaning this up to only have a single 'return'.):

```
  public static int GetRouteDataValueAsNumber(HttpRequest request, string propertyName)
  {
     if ((request == null) ||
         (request.RequestContext == null) ||
         (request.RequestContext.RouteData == null) ||
         (request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[propertyName] == null))
     {
        return -1;
     }

     try
     {
        return System.Convert.ToInt32(request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[propertyName]);
     }
     catch
     {
     }

     return -1;
  }
```

Now when I need to read a routing value (like a prediction ID), I do the following:

```
  long _predictionId = System.Convert.ToInt64(WebAppUtils.GetRouteDataValueAsNumber(Request, "id"));
```

Works great! Now my site feels like an MVC app with friendly and self-documenting URLs.

Oh, last thing, you also need to enable HTTP Redirection as follows:

Start => Control Panel => Program => Turns Windows Features On => Internet Information Services => World Wide Web Services => Common HTTP Features => (select checkbox for) HTTP Redirection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this would be a programmatic approach using the `System.Web.Routing` assembly.

This basically works by including the `UrlRoutingModule` in your `web.config`, and defining patterns that resolve the target page based on matching routes.  If you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC, then you have used this routing strategy before, but MVC is not necessary to use Routing.

### Here are some resources to help you get started:

- [MSDN Documentation for the System.Web.Routing namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx) - official documentation
- [Scott Gu on URL Routing for MVC](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) - ** Note that this article explains routing in the context of an ASP.NET MVC application, however, the same methodology will work regardless of whether or not you are using MVC*
- [ASP.NET Routing... Goodbye URL rewriting, by Chris Cavanagh](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/) - An explanatory article
- [Exploring System.Web.Routing, by Justin Etheredge](http://www.codethinked.com/exploring-systemwebrouting) - A case study explaining how to use routing independently of the MVC architecture

### About Windows Azure ...

If you take this approach, it doesn't really matter that you are using Windows Azure.  However, I found an [article by Michael Kennedy called **ASP.NET Routing in Windows Azure Using WebForms**](http://www.develop.com/aspnet_azure), explaining how to easily deploy such a solution on Windows Azure.  The article even has a [sample project for download](http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/ct.ashx?id=210f6623-b67e-4b6b-835e-1576bc2cfb3c&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.michaelckennedy.com%2fSamples%2fAzureRoutingSample.zip).

Comment: Thanks for this great feedback. Really appreciate it. I'm aware that if we had been based on MVC, this would be much easier. However, we came up with our own framework that leverages JSON-based WebMethods and PageMethods and client-side rendering via jQuery, so your links that are not MVC-dependent will be especially useful.

Comment: @Armchair Bronco, all the links I posted contain code that is not MVC dependent.  I understand you are not using MVC.  The reason I posted the articles is because the MVC-specific articles demonstrated the most readable examples of the Routing API.

Comment: Exactly. I remember when I was evaluating MVC in the early days when we were trying to decide on an architecture. It reminded me so much of the old ASP days, with its heavy reliance on alligator tags <%= bla %> that I said: "Forget it! Thinking of those days gives me a headache." The links that you provided are a great starting point, so a big thumbs up. One question, is ignoring the human readable hyphenated title considered "best practice"? In other words, should we be relying on an ID, or should we implement something that guarantees each title is unique, and just use that instead?

Comment: @Armchair Bronco, Check this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397925/does-the-hyphenated-title-matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397925/does-the-hyphenated-title-matter?).  There are clearly successful websites that use an ID and ignore the hyphenated slug.  It would certainly be harder to remember the url, though, with a dependency on an integer ID, but I doubt people will be memorizing URLs about Paris Hilton winning the Nobel peace prize in any event.  Either way, you could always expand on the routing resolution after your app is already working

Comment: Good point. Although if Paris Hilton were, by some miracle, to win the Nobel Peace Prize, then all bets would be off! It would become the hottest URL on the Internet! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Azure web roles have the IIS7 Url Rewriting module installed - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573358.aspx

The "how to" for this module is at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

For your Paris example, you basically need to setup a rule that maps the url

http://www.ipredikt.com/predictions/14/paris-hilton-will-win-the-nobel-peace-prize

to

http://www.ipredikt.com/details.aspx?id=14

This is something like:

Pattern -

```
^predictions/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

Action -

```
 details.aspx?id={R:1}
```

For more on defining these rules see http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Thanks for the real-world example. Seems like doing this is going to be easier than I thought. I had some trouble doing this against my http://localhost server 6 months ago when I first gave it a whirl, but now that we have our production and staging servers up on Azure, I bet things will be go a lot smoother.

Comment: If you have problems on your localhost server, then maybe give IIS Express a whirl. And having used Azure, I'll take your money on that bet ;)

Comment: There's no denying that Azure does not make any of this stuff "trivial", but nothing's worse than trying to coerce http://localhost:3737 into acting like something that's live on the web.  The beauty of Azure is the ability to do your work against your staging server, work out all the kinks, and the flip the switch. Presto-change-o, the staging server is now the production server.  But your point is totally valid.